# Build in release mode when publishing Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

The following command builds and publishes my functions to Azure. But it always builds in debug mode - how do I make it switch to building in release mode?

```
func azure functionapp publish NAME_OF_MY_FUNCIONS_RESOURCE
```

Update: When I compare the file sizes of the dlls in the Debug, Release and publish folders, the ones in the publish folder matches the ones in the Debug folder, and not the ones in the Release folder.

```
# Paths that I am comparing.
FunctionApps\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\bin
FunctionApps\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\bin
FunctionApps\bin\publish\bin     <-- Matches Debug\netstandard2.0\bin.
```

Comment: Did you get any prompt it is in debug mode? On my side, I see [project]\bin\publish generate and files in this folder is published.

Comment: No I don't. The reason I can see that is compiling in debug mode is that it writes the full path to the assemblies that it is using, and they are the ones in the `\bin\Debug` folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question on GitHub and got answer there.

```
func azure functionapp publish NAME_OF_MY_FUNCIONS_RESOURCE \
  --dotnet-cli-params -- "--configuration Release"
```

More details on GitHub: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/670.

Answer (score 1):

You may be confused about these output. (I work with c# function on Windows).

[image]

Actually right now when we use `func azure functionapp publish` to publish, both debug and publish content will be generated. And this command consumes files in publish folder.

To proof this, check the difference between Debug and publish folder. `local.settings.json` is copied to the former but not for the later, because the file is only useful in local dev. After I publish my function, this file is not uploaded. So I think the publish does work correctly in publish folder.

**Update**

Release folder doesn't exist if I only leverage function cli, you probably compare with Release folder generated by VSCode/VS or just `dotnet publish --configuration Release` manually.

Your assumption should be right. Even though the code to publish is put in `bin\publish` folder, it is built in debug mode. Have checked PDB file `functionappname.pbd`, its size is identical to the one in Debug folder(bigger than the one in Release folder).

Found the [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/670) you opened, let's wait for Aure team's reply.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information. I am, however, not able to confirm that both debug and release content is generated. And the files in the publish folder matches the ones in the Debug folder. I've updated my question with these findings.

Comment: @JanAagaard Sorry I made a mistake, folder name doesn't represent build mode. Let's wait for function team's reply.

Comment: Thanks again. And yes, I have been using Visual Studio's publish feature before, so that might explain why I had a publish folder in the first place. I might end up using Visual Studio or `msbuild` to publish instead of the `func` command.